# Raising a complex number to a large power

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to confirm my solution to a complex number problem:

Given a complex number $z = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}i$, I need to compute $z^{150}$ in cartesian form and polar form.

$r = |z| = 1$, meaning it will be unaffected by the power of 150.

$\theta = \tan^{-1}(2\sqrt{2}) = 1.231$ radians

Now using de Moivre's theorem,

$z^{n} = r^{n}(cos(n\theta) + isin(n\theta))$

$\implies$ $z^{150} = cos(150\cdot\theta) + isin(150\cdot\theta)$

$\implies$ $z^{150} = cos(184.65) + isin(184.65)$ ... after subbing in $\theta = 1.231$.

$\implies$ $z^{150} = cos(2.438) + isin(2.438)$ ... since $184.65$ mod $2\pi = 2.438$

However, the solution I have gives the following calculation:

$z^{150} = exp(150 i \cdot 1.230959417) = exp(2.5416387 i) = cos(2.5416387) + i sin(2.5416387)$

Wolfram Alpha backs up my answer of $\theta = 2.438, but I'm wondering if I'm misinterpreting the question or if there's something I'm missing. Is there another way of multiplying radians?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Up to understandable issues involving truncation of the number of decimal places and rounding, you appear to have performed the calculation correctly. I have no idea where the "solution" got its $2.541$ angle from. (Incidentally I also don't know why anybody would bother reducing the angle mod $2\pi$ when the numerical result, which is a cosine of a decimal expression no matter what, would be computed, if at all, using a calculator, irrespective of what interval the angle happened to lie in. But I agree with your calculations.)

Comment: [Keeping a lot more digits in the intermediate calculations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=150+arctan%282+sqrt%282%29%29-58pi), I get approximately $2.4315$ for the final angle. By rounding some figures accurately to fewer digits than is advisable for this problem (such as using $3.14$ as an approximation for $\pi$), I was able to get $2.53$. I don't know how they get a result greater than $2.54.$

Comment: You have $1.2305<\theta <1.2315$ and without any more known precision, this gives an uncertainty in $150\theta$ of up to $\pm 0.075$.